# What are the names of screens used in "Basic calculators"?

Tags: led, low-power, monitor, calculator

I was trying to power a basic calculator that day with a power source and I started from 0V going up to 1.5 v I noticed the calculator screen turning out to show a "0", but I could not do any calculations. I also, noticed that powering the screen did not even pull 1mA which is the minimum I can see from my power source.

[image]

Do those screens have a name? it would be cool to use them in Ultra low power applications.

Comment: These are simple 7-segment LCDs

Comment: Not to be confused with the color, multi-layer, super-fast screens most of us use with our computers - those take far more power because of how much harder they are working.  These simple, slow, monochrome LCD screens (with no backlight) use surprisingly little power.

Comment: FWIW, the e-ink displays do not use power *at all* for a static picture.

Comment: I seem to recall they work slower down to freezing temperatures then not at all. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Liquid_crystal  and https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Electronic_paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid Crystal Displays, or LCDs, use a material (the ‘liquid crystal’) which can be polarized in segments by an applied voltage.

The display glass is made up of several layers and mirror on the back. When a segment is de-energized (polarized), it is in opposite polarity with the filter, blocking the light and making the segment appear dark. Energize the segment, it stops being polarized and light passes through.

This type used in a calculator is called a ‘Twisted Nematic’, or TN display. The TN display polarizing voltage uses almost no current, so indeed these displays are very low power.

More here: https://electrosome.com/lcd-display-fundamentals/

There are a wide variety of pre-made LCD modules on the market, which include driver ICs. You can also get custom-made LCDs for a price.

You need to check what voltage the calculator controller actually needs. It may be that it needs more than 1.5V to operate.

Comment: How do they control the number shown? Is that an external circuit?

Comment: The display glass module itself doesn’t have any active drivers. The calculator IC provides circuitry to make the LCD drive waveforms.

Comment: @AnwerAk Each segment is basically its own display. The calculator calculates which segments it needs to turn on.

Answer (score 1):

They are segment (as opposed to graphic) LCD displays (Liquid Crystal Display displays). There are two basic types, static and multiplexed. Static types have single common pin and the segment pins are driven with a 50% duty cycle square wave either in or out of phase depending on the segment state (in either state the average voltage is zero ideally, in practice mV). The static type is very low power and can be made quite stable with ambient temperature changes.

When there are too many segments for that to be practical, multiplexed displays are used that have two, three or more commons and a number of segment pins that is reduced to 1/2, 1/3 or less of the number of segments. This kind of display is driven with a complex waveform that keeps the average voltage of 'off' segments at least somewhat below a threshold voltage, and the average voltage of 'on' segments at least somewhat above. Since the threshold voltage of the material is invariably temperature-sensitive, a manual or automatic 'contrast' control may be required for wide temperature applications such as automobile displays. Usually for multiplexed LCDs a driver
For very low temperature applications, such as automotive displays, different LCD materials are used that can require different voltages.

Colloquially, the raw LCD (no drivers or other electronics) is called the 'glass'.
A typical static LCD is [here](https://www.lumex.com/spec/LCD-S401C71TR.pdf)

[image]

And a multiplexed type (4 commons) [here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Varitronix%20PDFs/VIM-878.pdf) It has (14+2)*8 = 128 segments, but only 34 pins rather than the 129 that would be required with static drive.

Answer (score -1):

Many calculators use **LCD displays** which are low power.

Comment: "D" in LCD stands for "Display" : )

Comment: As others have said, what you've written is Liquid Crystal Display displays, which is a mistake. It's 'LCDs'.